# Can I going to access django orm's column as a string + variable?

Tags: django-queryset, django-orm

Can I going to access django orm's column as a string + variable?

examply is it possible?

```
    for x in range(i, 98)
        CategoryNick.obejcts.filter(author=request.user).update("ca"+(x+1)=F('ca'+x))
```

or is there a another way?

thakns for let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it with a dictionary, and do dictionary unpacking. In fact we can do the updates in bulk with:

```
data = {'ca{}'.format(x+1): F('ca{}'.format(x)) for x in range(i, 98)}
CategoryNick.objects.filter(
    author=request.user
).update(**data)
```

We here thus will perform a single update query, that will look like:

```
UPDATE app_categorynick
SET ca2 = ca1, ca3 = ca2, ca4 = ca3, …, ca98 = ca97
```

Notice the two asterisks (`**`) in front. If you call a function `f(**some_dict)`, with `some_dict` for example `some_dict = {'a': 4, 'b': 2}`, it will call `f` with `f(a=4, b=2)`.

That being said. Usually if you have an arbitrary number of values stored in a model, it is not a good idea to do this with a huge number of columns. Since you can never know an extra column is needed. Usually one makes an extra model, and defines a many-to-one relation from that model to the target model.